# Adding a new class member to ArrayList, auto-incrementing the identifier

Tags: java, class, arraylist

**Context**
I have a simple class of students (see at the end if necessary). In another class I want to populate an array of students, and have the user add a student of his own. The students are labeled s01, s02, etc and I would like the program to assign the next identifier to the new student automatically.

**My dysfunctional code** It starts by adding 2 students then prompts the user to create a new one.

```
public static List<Student> populate(){
        //skipped a few lines of student creation

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(s01);
        students.add(s02);

        //The list now contains the 2 students
        //Now I want to add a student myself
        System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
        String NewName = reader.next();

        //I want the program to recognize that there are 2 students in the arrayList and 
        //Automatically make next Student s03. 
        //I can figure out how to determine it is the 3 that is needed
        //But I don't think the identifier can be a string. I tried this: 

        String nextStudent = "s03"
        Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName);
        //          ^How can I set this to be a variable?
        students.add(nextStudent);
        return students;
    }
```

**My student class**

```
public class Student {

    String name;
    int age;
    String program;

    public Student(String StudentName){
        this.name = StudentName;
    }

    public void PrintInfo(){
        System.out.println(name + " is a " + age +" year old student in " + program);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Also I am using the term "identifier" but I am relatively certain it is the wrong term. If someone could cue me in on what it is called, that would be great!

Comment: I really don't understand your problem, why not just use what you have: `Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName);` ?

Comment: Because I would like to have it in a loop, where the user can add as many students as they want. And so it should go s01, s02, s03, s04 by itself. That's why I wanted to make it a variable that ca increment.

Comment: @DavidG You can't set variable names at run time. If you want to loop through the ArrayList use: `for (Student s : students){ // do something }`

Comment: OK I was under the impression it was a necessity. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName);
>             ^How can I set this to be a variable?
> ```

It can't. But you don't need to: just remove `String nextStudent = "s03"`. There is no need for the variable to be called `s03`: provided the names of variables are unique, the actual variable name has no semantic impact on the program.

Comment: Because I would like to have it in a loop, where the user can add as many students as they want. And so it should go s01, s02, s03, s04 by itself. That's why I wanted to make it a variable that ca increment.

Comment: But you don't need the variable name to be anything in particular. Just create the instance in a loop and add it to the list. You simply *cannot* have dynamic variable names in Java.

Comment: Ok. I have managed to create students in a loop and dropped the "s0x" identifiers completely. Now I create students by adding them in a loop with `students.add(new Student(NewName));` where `NewName` is a user input String. However when doing this how can I set an age and a program? Usually I would write `s01.age = 3` but now I haven't even set a "s01" at all. Do you understand my question or should I ask a new one?

Comment: `Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName); students.add(nextStudent); nextStudent.age = 3;`.

Comment: I am not using nextStudent anymore, I create students using the line I wrote in the comment above. When doing that how do I subsequently refer to my students? I see your edit. Since it is in a loop, I cannot use `Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName);` because there cannot be multiple ones called nextStudent (or am I wrong?)

Comment: You are wrong. Each time through the loop, `nextStudent` refers to a new instance, because it is declared as `Student nextStudent = new Student(...);`

Comment: Nevermind it does work. I guess I don't understand object oriented as well as I though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automatically name your new `Student` based on the size of your `List`, you can use the following idiom:

```
students.add(new Student(String.format("s0%d", students.size() + 1)));
```

The code above performs the following operations inline:

- Formats a `String` with "s0" plus the size of your `students" list`+ 1`
- Passes that `String` (e.g. `"s03"`) to a `Student` constructor
- Creates a new `Student` using the constructor parametrized with that `String`
- Adds the new `Student` to your `List`

This should replace your code here, which won't compile:

```
String nextStudent = "s03"
Student nextStudent = new Student(NewName);
```

**Note**

The `String.format` idiom formats a `String` C-style, based on assumed data types and arguments.

The start of the `String` is a constant (`"s0"`) and won't "survive" a student list size greater than 9 (edge case for you).

The `"%d"` format indicates an integer number, whose value is given by `students.size() + 1`.

**Also note**

Variable names are `camelBack`, not `CamelCase` (which in turn, is reserved for the name of classes, interfaces and enums).

Answer (score 2):

To loop over your list of students you have **no need** to name them uniquely. Simply use the same pattern that you use for the first two students and then:

```
for (Student stud : students){
    // do stuff with each student here
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){    
    students.get(i) // now you can do whatever you want with the i'th student
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your students to be `s01, s02, s03, s04` and so on. So what you could do is hold an integer static variable inside your `Student` class to keep count of how many objects you've created so far and give them the appropriate name, something like:

```
public class Student {

    private static int counter = 0;

    String id;
    String name;
    int age;
    String program;

    public Student(String name, int age, String program) {
        //pass relevant info in the constructor
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.program = program;
        this.id = String.format("%02d", ++counter);
    }

    // rest of your methods
}
```

And then each time you add a `Student` to your `ArrayList`, it would automatically be given the subsequent "identifier":

```
public static List<Student> populate(){

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(new Student(/*student parameters*/));
    students.add(new Student(/*student parameters*/));

    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    String newName = reader.next();
    //do the same with age and program

    Student nextStudent = new Student(newName, newAge, newProgram);
    students.add(nextStudent);
    return students;
}
```

Note that it would only work if you're application is only running on one thread (for thread safety, change the `counter` variable to be `AtomicInteger`).

Answer (score 0):

You probablby need map to store your students with such assignments like: s01, s02 and so on...

```
Map<String, Integer> students = new HashMap<>();
//...
String nextStudent = "s" + Integer.toString(students.size());
students.put(nextStudent, new Student(NewName));
```